# Flutter / Dart - Access every element on List<Map>

Tags: flutter, dart

How can i get each `element` in the map and display `title, time etc.` using ListView.builder` in Dart/Flutter?

I have made a List (This fake response might be wrong formatted).

I just want to take each element from this List.

Thanks!

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> fakeRes = [
  {
    "elem1": {
      "items": [
        {
          "title": "this is a title",
          "time": "10:00:00",
          "imageUrl":
              "https://jpg",
          "stars": 2.0,
          "totalRatings": 255
        },
      ]
    },
  },
  {
    "elem2": {
      "items": [
        {
          "title": "this is a title",
          "time": "10:00:00",
          "imageUrl":
              "https://",
          "stars": 2.0,
          "totalRatings": 255
        },
      ]
    },
  }
];
```

My Code:

```
ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    itemCount: fakeRes.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
      return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(fakeRes[index].values.toList()[index]['recipes'].toString()),
           ],
          );
        }),
```

Comment: Is it possible to modify `fakeRes` structure as the example I will give you !

Answer (score 0):

```dart
fakeres[index]['elem'+$index]['items'][0]["title"]
```

This would return:

```
this is a title
```

Comment: Code only answers are allowed, but it's encouraged to explain the answer as well. Consider adding some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This code works.
See the correct JSON at the end.
It will create a ListView of Columns.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemCount: fakeRes.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
          Map res = fakeRes[index];
          return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            color: Colors.red,
              child: Column(
                  children: res
                      .map((key, val) => MapEntry(key, Text("$key: $val")))
                      .values
                      .toList()));
        });
  }
}

List<Map<String, dynamic>> fakeRes = [
  {
    "title": "this is a title",
    "time": "10:00:00",
    "imageUrl": "https://jpg",
    "stars": 2.0,
    "totalRatings": 255
  },
  {
    "title": "this is a title",
    "time": "10:00:00",
    "imageUrl": "https://",
    "stars": 2.0,
    "totalRatings": 255
  },
];
```